# python call read() after readline() do not get the whole rest file

Tags: python, file, readline, codec

I read a file and call `read()` after `readline()`, but the `read()` function does not return the rest of the content.

I want to read a utf-8 file named 'test.txt' using codecs.
The content is list below:

```
1572278
#*OQL[C++]: Extending C++ with an Object Query Capability.
#@José A. Blakeley
#year1995
```

And the code I used:

```
import codes;
a = codecs.open('test.txt','r','utf-8');
b = a.readline();
c = a.read();
```

when I run it, the thing I get is:

```
b:1572278
c:#*OQL[C++]: Extending C++ with an Object Query Capability.\r\n#@J
```

Here, `c` is not the rest of the whole file - I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Can you include the code that you use to print the contents of b and c?

Answer (score 3):

this is because of the way the `StreamReaderWriter` works. when you do `readline()` it fills up a `linebuffer` which isn't empty when you then call `read()`, reading the `codecs.py` code, this will shortcut to return whatever is in the buffer unless you specify a `size` that works for your input file.

If you want to use `os.path.getsize` as a hint for `read()`:

```
>>> import os
>>> a = codecs.open('test.txt', 'r', 'utf-8'); a.readline(); a.read(os.path.getsize('test.txt'))
u'1572278\n'
u'#*OQL[C++]: Extending C++ with an Object Query Capability.\n#@Jos\xe9 A. Blakeley\n#year1995\n'
```

Since you are slurping the file; you can do that first and use `StringIO` on top.

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> a = codecs.open('test.txt', 'r', 'utf-8'); 
>>> buff = StringIO.StringIO(a.read())
>>> buff.readline()
u'1572278\n'
>>> buff.read()
u'#*OQL[C++]: Extending C++ with an Object Query Capability.\n#@Jos\xe9 A. Blakeley\n#year1995\n'
```

Another simple solution is to call `read()` twice, once to get the buffered output and once more to slurp the rest.

```
>>> a = codecs.open('test.txt', 'r', 'utf-8'); a.readline(); a.read() + a.read()
u'1572278\n'
u'#*OQL[C++]: Extending C++ with an Object Query Capability.\n#@Jos\xe9 A. Blakeley\n#year1995\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

edit: I see.

Would this work for you?

```
import codecs

def line_get(fileobj):
    while 1:
        d = fileobj.readline()
        if d:
            yield d
        else:
            fileobj.close()
            break

a = codecs.open('input','r','utf-8')
b = a.readline()
c = [line for line in line_get(a)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The`read()`call seems get the rest of the file for me. Perhaps you're not outputting what was read properly -- however I can't tell since you didn't include the code that does that in your question.

BTW, you don't need to end lines of Python code with a semicolon like you do with C and C++ code.

```
import codecs
a = codecs.open('test.txt', 'r', 'utf-8')
b = a.readline()
c = a.read()
a.close()

print('b:%r' % b)
print('c:%r' % c)
```

Output:

```
b:u'\ufeff1572278\r\n'
c:u'#*OQL[C++]: Extending C++ with an Object Query Capability.\r\n#@Jos\xe9 A. Blakeley\r\n#year1995\r\n'
```